# Update parent component @Input property after component initialized

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having two child components and referring from parent and I'm trying to update @Input object after child component initialized

.html:

```
<div>
 <app-child-one></app-child-one>
 <app-child-two [data]="test"></app-child-two>

 <button (click)="onClick()">Clicked</button>
</div>
```

.ts:

```
test: string;

onClick() {
  this.test = 'Hello World !!';
}
```

By the time I clicked on the button both the child components are initialized, how could I update the data property value to the child component after clicking the button ??

Comment: Are you using any change detection strategy on your `<app-child-two>` component ?

Comment: I've ngAvfterViewInIt() no other detection strategy and looks like it's not helping much..

Comment: You just copy one of your child component in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @ViewChild you can achive this. Add id #appChildTwo in

```
<div>
 <app-child-one></app-child-one>
 <app-child-two [data]="test" #appChildTwo></app-child-two>

 <button (click)="onClick()">Clicked</button>
</div>
```

In .ts file of parent

```
import {  ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Declare class variable in parent

```
@ViewChild('appChildTwo') appChildTwo;
```

on button click. By using viewchild we get reference of the child component in parent's component file and then we can access all public member and function of child component using viewchild  refernce.

```
onClick() {
 this.test = 'Hello World !!';
if(this.appChildTwo)
  this.appChildTwo.data= 'Hello World !!';
}
```

Hope this will help you.